# How do I sync Tasks and Memos in Evolution using CalDav

Tags: sync, evolution, calendar, nextcloud

I'm trying to figure out how to sync evolution's 'task' and/or 'memo' functions with a remote server which is running NextCloud.  However, neither the tasks I create locally nor the tasks I create directly on the remote server sync with one another.  Within evolution, I am setting up a new task list with the following settings.

- Type: On Web
- Url: https://CLOUDSERVICE.com/remote.php/dav/calendars/USER/MYCALENDAR/
- Use a secure connection: x

As I understand it a CalDav calendar can include TODO items and so I'm trying to sync to the calendar MYCALENDAR which I can sync to via evolution's 'calendar' function.

Comment: This [link](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/synchronazing-notes/1676/8) seems relevant, but I'm still digesting the difference between VTODO and VJOURNAL and how they map to evolution's tasks and memos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, at least for Tasks.

The mistake I made was using Type: On Web.

The correct setting is Type: DavCal

This, of course, makes sense but is not what's listed on the official [evolution documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/tasks-caldav.html.en).